# starting an app after User_Present Action - not working

Tags: java, android

I would like to make an app that starts up every time the device is unlocked.

I'm new to Android and although I've read dozens of answers and the documentation there are just too many moving parts that I'm having a hard time troubleshooting.

Here is what I have ...

Structure

```
app
 - manifests
  -- AndroidManifest.xml
 - java
  -- DisplayMessageActivity.java
  -- MainActivity.java
 - res
 - UnlockReceiver.java
```

This is in  in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="UnlockReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This is my UnlockReceiver.java class

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.xywebsolutions.myapplication.MainActivity;

public class UnlockReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it my Structure? Do I need to add permissions before adding the receiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two changes and this issue was fixed:

1) The "UnlockReceiver" was moved into the java folder

```
app
 - manifests
  -- AndroidManifest.xml
 - java
  -- DisplayMessageActivity.java
  -- MainActivity.java
  -- UnlockReceiver.java
 - res
```

And

2) The receiver in the manifest needed *android:exported="true"* ...

```
<receiver android:name="UnlockReceiver" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any broadcast to start/stop video. 
You can use [onResume()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()) of activity lifecycle to start video. onResume will be called when activity becomes visible to user. 
[onPause()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) of activity to pause the video. You can also save current play position and start from that position when activity started again using [onSaveInstanceState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) function

For your case you can try this

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //start activity
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.test", "com.test.MainActivity");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
```

Comment: The issue is not starting the video. I want to open the app upon unlock. I've clarified my question.